# How to print characters without a new line, inside a while loop, and with sleep?

Tags: python, while-loop

I just realised, I can't print a character, on the same line with a delay.

```
import sys
import time
while True:
  sys.stdout.write('.')
  time.sleep(3.0)
```

I can only see the result after I break the loop with `CTRL+C`. Is there a solution for that?

I would like to see each point being printed `.....`, with a delay.

Comment: Can you not use `print` instead of `sys.stdout.write`?

Comment: Use `sys.stderr` if you want immediate output. Or call flush or set stdout to unbuffered. But `stderr` is the most idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output is probably buffered, it would eventually output to the terminal after the buffer was filled, but if you want it to be shown immediately you should explicitly flush output:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

in your loop

You can do this in one command in python 3:

```
print(".", end='', file=sys.stdout, flush=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample how it can be done. print() has a parameter that can be set like: `flush=True`:

```
from time import sleep
count = 0
while count < 20:
    print('.', end='', flush=True) # prints all in one line
    #print('.', flush=True) # prints on separate lines
    sleep(1)
    count += 1
```